# Change checked value checkboxes in a DataGridView with conditions

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to create a `DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn` in my `DataGridView` and change its `Checked status` depending on a query.
Here's how I try to do it :

```
DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn cbAdmin = new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn();
cbAdmin.CellTemplate = new DataGridViewCheckBoxCell();
bAdmin.HeaderText = "Administrateur";
cbAdmin.Name = "Admin";
cbAdmin.FalseValue = 0;
cbAdmin.TrueValue = 1;
dataGridViewAdmin.Columns.Insert(3, cbAdmin);

using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString))
{
    con.Open();
    for (int i = 0; i < dataGridViewAdmin.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT [isAdmin] FROM [TTH].[dbo].[Admins] WHERE [user] = '" + dataGridViewAdmin.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString() + "'", con))
        {
            using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                if (reader.Read())
                {
                    if (reader["isAdmin"].ToString() == "1")
                    {
                        dataGridViewAdmin.Rows[i].Cells["Admin"].Value = true;
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        dataGridViewAdmin.Rows[i].Cells["Admin"].Value = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }                    
    }
}
```

While debugging I see that I get true and false values where I need them but the checkboxes are all unchecked and I can't even check them in my program when they are clicked.

Comment: You are probably missing some kind of refresh at the end. `dataGridViewAdmin.Update()`?

Comment: Always use sql parameters to avoid sql injection. See https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2017/07/01/parameterized-queries.aspx

Comment: @Sinatr Just tried but no success.

Comment: @user1408786 This column values are filled by a query + the column is read only. Should I still do it ?

Comment: Can't you join this field in the initial SQL that fills the DataGridView and bind a CheckBoxColumn to it? Btw, if you cannot, don't try to force a value. Create the Column type, add a Name and a Header. Then set the Cell value to the value of the field.

Comment: Your config for `DataGridView` is correctly? I created new project with default `DGV` and insert `CheckBoxColumn`. Checked state is change normal by code.

Comment: @RezaAghaei I tried with true/false and 0/1

Comment: I had a datagrid check box column problem like this, I had to invalidate the datagrid to make my changes visible. i.e) dataGridViewAdmin.Invalidate();